# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jwt, mongoose-schema

I have data in the User table, but I can't find a user based on their id - `User.findById('kjsdfjsidjisj')`. Under the fetchuser function, if I `res.send({ user: user_id })` it correctly sends back the id in a string format after decoding the JWT token. But when I try `user = User.findById({ user_id })`, and sending user it gives me an error. Maybe I'm missing something in my query??

I don't know how to complete this promise, if this is one.

---

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const config = require('../config/dev');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function tokenForUser(user) {
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    return jwt.encode({ 
        sub: user.id,
        admin: user.admin
    }, config.secret);
}

exports.fetchuser = function (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.body.token;
    const secret = config.secret;
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret);

    const user_id = decoded.sub;

    const user = User.findById({ user_id })

    res.send({
        user: user
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `findById` takes an `id` as param, not an object. And you need a
>   callback to access the data.

```
User.findById(user_id, (err, user) => {
  res.send({
    user: user
  });
})
```